# how to match multiple words in string using regex?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match 3 words that can appear anywhere in the string:

```
Win
Enter
Now
```

All 3 words must exist in the string for it return as a match. But I am having issues for getting a match when all 3 words do exist.

Below is the regex I am using: http://regexr.com/39b83

```
^(?=.*?win)(?=.*?(enter))(?=.*?(now)).*
```

*Regex is working when all three words are within the same line*... when its spread out across the entire string on different lines, it is failing to match.

Any direction or help is appreciated.

Comment: And what issues are you having? (Are you trying to match *any* of those words, rather than all of them?)

Comment: It is returning no match even when the string includes all three words.

Comment: Can you give an example of a string that you tried, please? It works fine for me – even on RegExr.

Comment: If this is something quick and dirty, I'd just run several greps. `grep win filename.txt | grep enter | grep now`

Comment: @minitech, try this http://regexr.com/39b83, I am seeing no match in the example...

Comment: @Rick i didn't find any line which has the above mentioned three strings. It's better to use a html parser rather than a regex.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @Rick: What line do you think it ought to match in that example? The closest I see is “WIN THIS GORGEOUS BURBERRY TOTE<br>FILLED WITH LUXURY<br>VINCENT LONGO COSMETICS!”, which only includes one of the words. If you want it to match three lines, don’t use a multiline match like that.

Comment: @minitech: i was hoping it would return Win this... Enter Now.

Comment: @Rick which language are you running?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: sorry, c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `C#` would support `(?s)` DOTALL modifier. If yes then you could try the below regex,

```
(?i)(?s)win.*?enter.*?now
```

Comment: My apologies, I left out the requirements that all 3 works MUST exist.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it won't work if the order of the words is different

Comment: correct, as the order may be different, was wondering if this was possible through regex before iterating programatically with a single pattern.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: =) It works. Taking your comment above into consideration if the order is unknown and may change is it better to programmatically iterate?

Comment: if the order is unknown, you may use `(?i)(?s)(?:win|enter|now).*?(?:win|enter|now).*?(?:win|enter|now)` but it also matches `win foo win foo bar win`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: one flow is that if WIN does not exist it will still return as match as long as it finds enter or now the 2nd and 3rd time.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want to match words like center (with the word "enter"), I would use:

```
/(\benter\b)|(\bwin\b)|(\bnow\b)/
```

Link to [Fiddler](http://regexr.com/39b8i)

Comment: My apologies, I left out the requirements that all 3 works MUST exist.

Comment: @Rick in which order ? if you don't know the order it'd be easier to run each word separately

Comment: in no particular order. the issue I am having is primarily when the three words are not in the same line it does not find a match...

Comment: @Rick may i know the expected output for the above input string?

Comment: @Rick if you don't know the order and you want to make sure all the three words are present, there are 3! options that you have to check, that's not a very complicated regex - just a very long one. It'll be easier to read and maintain if you'll check each word separately like I suggested on the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
/(win|enter|now)/gi
```

[image: regex diagram]

Comment: My apologies, I left out the requirements that all 3 works MUST exist.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to match the lines on which these words appear, across up to three lines. That’s not really easy, but:

```
/^.*win.*(?:\s+.*)?enter.*(?:\s+.*)?now.*|^.*win.*(?:\s+.*)?now.*(?:\s+.*)?enter.*|^.*enter.*(?:\s+.*)?win.*(?:\s+.*)?now.*|^.*enter.*(?:\s+.*)?now.*(?:\s+.*)?win.*|^.*now.*(?:\s+.*)?win.*(?:\s+.*)?enter.*|^.*now.*(?:\s+.*)?enter.*(?:\s+.*)?win.*/igm
```

[should do it.](http://regexr.com/39b8o)

Answer (score 0):

It 's because the dot doesn't match the newline character. To change this, you have to ways. The first, use the s modifier (that allows the dot to match newlines):

```
(?s)^(?=.*\bwin\b)(?=.*\benter\b)(?=.*\bnow\b).*
```

But this feature isn't always available (for example in Javascript). The second way consists to replace the dot with `[\s\S]` (a character class that matches all the characters):

```
^(?=[\s\S]*\bwin\b)(?=[\s\S]*\benter\b)(?=[\s\S]*\bnow\b)[\s\S]+
```